# How to view column values in views using ORM in Kohana

Tags: orm, kohana-3

I have following relations in my model.

```
  protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'business' => array(),
    'category' => array(),
    'user' => array(),
);
```

I fetch records from events table. But in view I need to display some column values from category table. My model function query is as follows -

```
return $this->where('end_time', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->order_by('start_time', 'ASC')
            ->limit(50)
            ->find_all();
```

I could display all the columns of events table properly. But when I tried to display "title" column from category table as follows -

```
foreach($events as $event):
echo $event->category->title;
endforeach;
```

it displays nothing.
This is a maintenance project and I found the code works properly for online copy. Is there something I'm missing in configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if it works online, it should work locally (maybe the only difference is the data itself?).

You can use `ORM::with()` when loading results to load related one-to-one relations eagerly:

```
$titles = ORM::factory('title')->with('category')->find_all();
```